# Transition from SQL Server to MySQL (no data migration) - what's the difference?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, hosting

I've written my website using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server (used a SQL Server instance which ran locally on my machine).

I'm about to upload my site to a hosting provider. However, his DB works under MySQL. I don't care about the data already in the DB itself. It's mostly mock data and a few tables which I don't mind rewriting. But how do I go about the transition from SQL Server to MySQL? How does this influence my queries inside my code? is it the same code syntax? Will I have to recreate the table definitions? In my project I used LINQ to SQL.

Am I forced to look for a host with SQL Server capabilities (i.e. licenses)? (I hope not...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to SQL works with MS SQL Server only...so if you want to keep using it, you need to find a host with a MSSQL database.

Comment: good to know. Turns out I can get MSSQL support after all, so ...  everything went better than expected :-D

http://www.orderoftheflame.co.uk/RandomImages/everything_went_better_than_expected.jpg

Comment: @Tom Teman - Linq is **not** SQL Server specific. There are providers for other databases - see here: http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/

Answer (score 3):

You *may* be able to transition smoothly, but I greatly doubt this will be the case.

The differences are many and whether you could depends on what features you used when developing.

If you kept to one of the [standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization), you may be in luck.

See a comparison sheet on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems).

In regards to the Linq aspect of your question - you should be able to use a Linq provider for MySql instead of MSSql without a problem.

Here is a link to one: http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/

---

If you do decide to go with the MySql hosting, I suggest you *test* all aspects of you application to ensure they are working as expected.